# XSL FO: How to determine page break?

Tags: xsl-fo, page-break

I've a situation where I have 2 block-containers - if they are short enough, the should be on one page, separated by a line.
But if not, then the 2. block-container has to start on the next page and there should be NO line between them.

How can I do that (because I don't know how I can check if inside a flow is a page-break)? Is there any param I can use to check in FO, if the block starts after a page-break ore something else?

Thanks for any help !!

Frangoo

Answer (score 2):

You could set the following attribute in the second block container

```
keep-together.within-page="always"
```

With this the XSL-FO processor will make sure, that the whole block will remain on the same page. So it would look something like this:

```
<fo:block keep-together.within-page="always"> <!-- any other attribute as necessary -->
    ...
</fo:block>
```

Comment: Thanks, yeah that is working already. But the problem is to draw a line (or any other element) between that blocks, depending if there is a page-break or no.

Comment: I don't think that's possible with the XSL-FO definition. If you're really interested in the line you could try to get the number of pages rendered and use it to determine the drawing of the line.

Comment: Hmpf. I expected that it is not possible to do that. But how can I check in FO the number of pages? I can use IF only in XSLT, but there I don't know the number of pages, right? Anyway thanks for your answer!

Comment: You could always print a space area between the two blocks if separation is your only concern so far.